# How to divide a figure and convert it to decimal but the remainder

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to divide 9245 by 1000 and get 9.245, and then push this number to my textview.

my code gives me 9.0 and not the remainder. Hope do I keep the remainder?

```
String playerScore1 = gameInfo.getGame_time() / 1000;
playerscore1.setText(Double.toString(playerScore1));
```

Comment: add an `f` (for `float`) or `.0` (for `double`) directly after `1000`. You may want to rehearse the language basics, e.g. in this [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Turing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `getGame_time()` method does not return a `double/float`, you need to explicitly add `.0` to dividend, or cast it to `double/float` type.

```java
gameInfo.getGame_time() / 1000.0;
```

Java by default performs integer division, which truncates the decimal part of result. To force floating point division you can also use suffix notation:

```java
int/1000f
int/1000d
```

Answer (score 2):

use 1000.0 then it'll convert it into Double, if you divide it by 1000 it will automatically cast it into an integer. and use data type **Double** for playerScore1 as it will return Double not **String**

```
Double playerScore1 = gameInfo.getGame_time() / 1000.0;
playerscore1.setText(Double.toString(playerScore1));
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use object type. Use primitive `double` instead, to prevent unnecessary autoboxing.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but maybe he is a beginner and it will be easy for him to understand this. Also TextVIew needs String in setText() method so we have to convert it again that's why I used a variable

Answer (score 2):

When using arithmetic operators, Java will always widen to the widest type used. One exception to this rules are arithmetic operations on types `byte`, `char`, and `short`, they are always converted to `int`. This is the reason why

```
byte b = 1;
b = b + 1;
```

will fail to compile due to type mismatches. But funnily enough

```
byte b = 1;
b += 1;
```

will compile and work as expected.

Back to topic: If you divide two `int`s, you get an `int` as result. If you divide an `int` and a `float`, you will get a `float`, ... Thus, the easiest way to make your expression behave as you want it to is to make one of the values either a `float` or a `double`.

You can denote a float literal by appending an `f` or `F` to a floating point number.

For `double`, you can:

- just write a floating point number, they will default to `double`
- add a ´.0´ to an integer literal to make it a `double` literal
- append a `d` or `D` on a floating point number, to make it extra verbose that it is a `double`

Applying this to your code, one possible solution is:

```
double playerScore1 = gameInfo.getGame_time() / 1000.0;
```